# What are Iterators, C++?

Tags: c++, iterator

What are Iterators in C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064983/different-types-of-iterators/1065528#1065528, http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html

Comment: This is good source of info: http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/tpkarkka/alglib/k06/lectures/iterators.html

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Iterators are a way of traversing a collection of objects.  Typically, they allow you to access an STL (Standard Template Library) container sequentially in ways similar to accessing a classical C array with a pointer.  To access an object through an iterator, you dereference it like a C pointer.  To access the next object in a collection, you use the increment (++) operator.  Some containers have multiple kinds of iterators that allow you to traverse the collection in different ways.

Answer (score 12):

Though it initially seems fairly obvious, this is actually a rather deeper question than you may realize. Along with Paul McJones, Alexander Stepanov (designer of the original, for anybody who's not aware of that) recently released a book named *Elements of Programming* (aka EOP). The entirety of chapter six in that book is devoted specifically to iterators, and quite a bit of the rest of the book relates closely to iterators as well. Anybody who really wants to know iterators in full detail might consider reading this book.

Warning: EOP is *not* for the faint of heart. It's relatively short (~260 pages), but *quite* dense. Speaking from experience, the early going is a bit disconcerting. My initial reaction to the first chapter was more or less "well, this is so obvious it's hardly worth reading. I did start programming before last week, after all!"

Fortunately, I did look at the exercises, and tried to do a couple -- and even though I had thought of the subjects as obvious, the exercises demand rigorous proofs. It's a bit like being asked to prove (in a mathematical sense) that water is wet. You end up just about needing to read the chapter a couple of times just to get past your own preconceived notion that you already know the answers, so you can look at the real question -- what does "wet" really mean; what are the fundamental characteristics of "wetness"?

Comment: It's such a pleaseure to come on S.O to find answers like these. +1

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to a book I should have known about (if not read) before.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator

Something that lets you go through everything in an array, one by one.

In c++, i think you're talking about "for_each" ... As far as I know, C++ doesn't actually have "foreach" unlike languages like C#.  However, the standard template library has it.

Comment: It is certainly more than arrays, in fact the very goal of the iterators in C++ is to abstract away the collection itself and its properties so that algorithms dealing with iterators can be used over any type of collection :)

Answer (score 2):

From p. 80 of [*Accelerated C++*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X):

> An iterator is a value that
>
> - Identifies a container and an element in the container
> - Lets us examine the value stored in that element
> - Provides operations for moving between elements in the container
> - Restricts the available operations in ways that correspond to what the container can handle efficiently

Answer (score 1):

They're a representation of a position within a sequence. On their own they're little more than curiosities, but when dereferenced they result in the value contained within the sequence at the position it represents.

Answer (score 1):

If you come from higher-level languages like Java or Python, you may have noticed C++ doesn't have any *built-in* complex types but only primitives like `int`, `double` or `char`. Since C++ was designed to be extremely efficient, whenever you need to use any collection type that is used to hold other values, it makes sense to create a new custom class. In fact, this is the way how C++ combines lower-level control and higher-level abstractions.

The [Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) provides a standartised collection of those classes that you can use to hold multiple values under a single entity. Primarily, they were created because raw C arrays are not flexible enough and the containers provide developers with smoother developer experience as they:

- dynamically expand and shrink without any developer effort;
- provide multiple useful interfaces with the data (`size()`, `upper_bound()`, etc);
- simplify memory management with [Resource Acquisition is Initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii).

So far, so good. Standard containers like `vector` or `list` give developers greater flexibility without much performance loss. However, since they are custom classes defined with C++ semantics, they need to provide also a way to access the data they hold. One could argue a simple `operator[]` or `next()` method could do the trick, and indeed you can do this, however the STL took inspiration from C and created a way to be able to access container items not depending on the container object itself: **iterators**.

Under the hood, iterator is nothing but an object that wraps a pointer to a value with a few operator overloading. You can use iterators in a similar way how you use pointers to array:

- you can pass iterators around and iterate through containers even if you don't have the access to the container objects themselves;
- you can dereference and move iterator with incrementation.

This is the primary purpose of iterators: to serve as pointers to container items. Because different containers store different items in different ways (`std::vector` uses contiguous block of memory, `std::list` stores nodes elsewhere connected with pointers, `std::map` uses hashing key in associative array), iterators are useful to provide a common interface that will be implemented in every separate container. In fact, this is the very reason that allows containers like `std::vector`, `std::array` or `std::map` to be enumerated with range-based for loops:

```cpp
std::vector<int> grades = {4, 5, 1, 8, 10};
for (int grade : grades) std::cout << grade << " ";
//-> 4 5 1 8 10
```

This for loop is just syntactic sugar for using iteration:

```cpp
std::vector<int> grades = {4, 5, 1, 8, 10};
std::vector::iterator it = grades.begin();
for (; it != grades.end(); ++it) std::cout << grade << " ";
//The output is the same.
```

You may have noticed some common interfaces iterators use, precisely they:

- overload the `*` operator to dereference an item;
- overload the `++` operator to move the iterator one item forward;
- overload the `==` and `!=` operators to compare if they point to the same value;
- are usually defined as a nested friend class (you access them with `<container>::iterator`, although you can entirely define iterator as a separate class.

Notice also that all containers that support containers should provide `begin()` method that returns the iterator to the first item, as well as `end()` to return an iterator to the item **after the last one**. The reason why it points to the location past the final one is because it is used to evaluate if the iterator exhausted all items: had `end()` pointed to the last item, the looping condition would be `it <= grades.end()`. Instead pointing to the next location after the container allows it evaluate it with a simple less check, which is the same reason why arrays begin with zero. Aside from them, there's also `rbegin()` and `rend()` functions that provide reversed iterator that goes from the end to the start and its `++` operator actually goes to the beginning.

## Implementing a custom iterator

To make it completely clear, let's implement our own custom iterator for a wrapper around plain arrays.

```cpp
template<typename T, unsgined int Capacity> class Array {
    T data[Capacity];
    int count;
    friend class Iterator;
public:
    Array(const std::initializer_list args) {
       for (int step = 0; step < args.size(); step++)
          data[step] = args[step;
    }
    int size() : count;
    T& operator[](int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > capacity) throw
           std::out_of_range("Index out of range.");
        return data[index];
    }
    Iterator<T> begin() {
       return &data; //Pointer to array yield the
                     //address to their first item.
    }
    Iterator<T> end() {
       return &(data + Capacity);
    }
};

template<typename T> class Iterator {
    T* reference;
public:
    Iterator(const Array<T>& array) {
       reference = array.begin();
    }
    T* operator*() {
       return reference;
    }
    Iterator<T> operator++() {
       return ++reference; //This is array-specific implementation detail.
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator<T>& other) : *reference != *other;
};

int main() {
   Array<int> array = {4, 5, 10, 12, 45, 100};
   Iterator<int> it = array.begin();
   while (it != array.end()) {
      std::cout << *it;
      ++it;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see, dividing iterator as a separate class creates a need to specify its type separately as well, which is the reason why it's usually defined as a nested class in its container.

There is also [`<iterator>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator) header that provides some useful facilities for standard iterators, such as:

- `next()` function that increments the iterator;
- `prev()` function that returns the iterator ` step before;
- `advance(int)` that moves iterator n steps forward;
- overloaded operators to compare iterators;
- other iteration-related additions.

If you need to write a custom iterator for your own highly-specific container that isn't present in STL, you should remember that iterators are used as a median between containers and algorithms, and for your own container you should pick the proper type of iterator (*input, output, forward, bidirectional or random access*) to support a number of standard algorithms out of the hand.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and it would be worth adding it to the linked duplicate.