# dereference a pointer and then take the address of dereference

Tags: c++, pointers

I read STL and a usage of pointer puzzles me.

```
destroy(&*first);
```

first is a pointer, then "&*first" is equal to first, why not use first directly?
destroy is declared as follow:

```
void destroy(T* pointer)
```

T is a template parameter.

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely due to operator overloading. `first` is the name typically given to iterators, which overload `operator*` to return a reference to the pointed to element of the container then `operator&` is used to get the address of the variable the iterator was pointing to. You can read more about iterators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305014/what-are-iterators-c).

However, if `first` is a pointer and not a user defined iterator, then yes you can just use `first` directly. Note that pointers can be iterators (specifically, `RandomAccessIterator`s).

Comment: Strictly speaking, pointers are iterators, so the last part isn't that true.

Comment: @chris Yeah, true. Edited to take this into account.

Answer (score 3):

If the argument is already a raw pointer, then `&*` combination does nothing, as you already noted. However, if the argument is a class type with overloaded unary `*` operator, then `&*` is no longer a no-op.

The classic usage of `&*` pattern is to convert a "generic" pointer into a raw pointer. For example, if `it` is an iterator associated with a vector element, then `&*it` will give you an ordinary raw pointer to that vector element.