# Passing beginning and ending positions of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I see that many functions require the beginning and ending positions of an array/vector.
I have two doubts, one in arrays and the second in vectors:

1. This code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int arr[4] = {5, 3, 4, 7};
sort(begin(arr), end(arr));
for(int& x : arr) cout << x << " ";
return 0;
}
```

is fine as .begin() and .end() return the pointers to the first and last elements of the array respectively (btw please correct me if I am wrong anywhere).

But please explain how this code works:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int arr[4] = {5, 3, 4, 7};
sort(arr, arr + 4);
for(int& x : arr) cout << x << " ";
return 0;
}
```

---

2. I understand if you want to sort (or perform any other function on) the whole vector, you can use .begin() and .end().

But what if you want to sort only a portion of the vector? Like the vector between left position L and right position R. How would you do that by using .begin and .end only (without slicing the vector)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look to [std::begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)

Comment: The notion is quite simply that you wouldn't use `.end()` for the case of a partial vector sort. You also don't have to start at `.begin()`. `.end()` is **not** the last element. Your C-array code example could be written better using `<iterator>` or `std::array`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Iterators, C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305014/what-are-iterators-c)

Comment: `int arr[4]` **has** no `.begin()`, `.end()`, or any other members. So the 1st bit of code you posted can't possibly be "fine". I guess you transcribed wrongly. Please paste actual code.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you should have written.

```
sort(begin(arr), end(arr));
```

because `int[]` is a builtin-type (from C) and does not have any member-function.
There exists overloads of `std::begin()` and `std::end()` suitable for `T[]` as shown above.

In C, using just the *name* of an array is an expression that *decays* to the beginning of this array.
For example, in:

```
int arr[4] = {5, 3, 4, 7};
int *p = arr;
```

`p` is a pointer initialised with the address of the first element in the array.
It is equivalent to

```
int *p = &(arr[0]);
```

Moreover, in C, there exists something called *pointer-arithmetic*.
This means that you can increment, decrement, compute the difference... with pointers.
Here, `p+4` means *the pointer which relates to the fourth element after the one pointed-to by `p`*; in this specific example, it is just after the end of your array.
So, back to your second example, `arr` is equivalent to `begin(arr)` and `arr+4` is equivalent to `end(arr)`.

We should not know any details about the exact nature of the *iterators* returned by `std::begin()` and `std::end()`; the only thing we know is that they behave as *metaphors* of pointers, in order to tell where an element is, to move to the next element...
But when the storage for these elements is a contiguous portion of memory (like `T[]`, `std::array<T>`, `std::vector<T>`...), internaly they are nothing more than pointers (we should not know... but we know ;^)
Moreover, in this specific contiguous storage case, a plain-true-real pointer is the perfect metaphor for a pointer... That's why `std::sort()` that was designed with iterators in mind also works with simple pointers as `arr` and `arr+4`.

You might be puzzled by the fact that the end position points-to a non-existing element (right after the last element in the array).
This is a convention for many algorithms: we specify a half-open interval, the first bound is included, the second bound is excluded.
So the algorithm will never access this *one-step-too-far* element; it will stop just before reaching it.
This is consistent with the classical `for()` loop: imagine you want five iterations, you will write `for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)` to specify `0` and `5` as bounds, but you will actually use the values `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` but NOT `5`.

When it comes to sorting just a portion of the array, you can use arithmetic on pointers or on iterators.

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr)+L, std::end(arr)-R);
std::sort(arr+L, arr+4-R);
```

assuming L and R are the number of elements you don't want to sort on each extremity of the array.

Comment: The technical parts of this answer are all OK, and I don't see any ambiguity. However, I think the answer might be a bit inaccessible to the novices which struggle with questions like this. @gabrupro, if you want to chime in, please let us know if this is clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

> is fine as .begin() and .end() return the pointers to the first and last elements of the array

Both functions return *iterators*, not pointers:

> An iterator is any object that, pointing to some element in a range of elements (such as an array or a container), has the ability to iterate through the elements of that range using a set of operators (with at least the increment (++) and dereference (*) operators).

(https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/)

Let's check what the signature of `std::sort`. It is basically

```
template<class RandomIt>
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

There are some requirements for `RandomIt` above: From [cppreference.com:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

1. RandomIt must meet the requirements of ValueSwappable and LegacyRandomAccessIterator.
2. The type of dereferenced RandomIt must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable and MoveConstructible.

Bullet 2 is a requirement on the type of the array-elements. Let's look at 1.: What is a [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)?

> A LegacyRandomAccessIterator is a LegacyBidirectionalIterator that can be moved to point to any element in constant time.

Basically this a pointer-like structure that allows to be incremented by an arbitrary value (`i + 5` is ok), it provides *random access* (that is your usual `operator[]` array access). This is exactly what the pointer `arr` is.

In summary, `std::sort` expects a random access iterator as arguments and `arr` is one.

> But what if you want to sort only a portion of the vector?

Since `arr.begin()/arr.end()` are a random-access iterator you can just increment and decrement them:

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr) + 2, std::end(arr) - 1);
```

You need be be cautious to not access elements out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 0):

For sorting vector partially you can use std::partial_sort

```
vector<int> v = { 1, 3, 1, 10, 3, 3, 7, 7, 8 }; 

// Using std::partial_sort 
std::partial_sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3, v.end());
```

Comment: This is correct code, but probably not the answer to the question above. It looks at **all** elements in `v`, not just the first 3.

Answer (score -1):

1. Have a look to those function. [std::begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end).
2. For second part, you might need to move your iterator by index using [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

   ```
   int main()
   {
      int arr[4] = {5, 3, 4, 7};
      auto pos = std::begin(arr);

      // Will move the 'begin' iterator one element further.
      std::advance(pos , 1);

      // Will sort the elements after the first index.
      std::sort(start, std::end(arr));
      for(int& x : arr) cout << x << " ";
      return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is a decent comment but a poor answer.

Comment: Currently making it properly, just wanted the OP to know what he could use

Comment: There's no need for `std::advance` when you know `+` works. `std::advance` has a very specific use: In generic code, where you don't know if you have a random-access iterator, but you can accept O(N) iterator increments, `std::advance` will select the best way to increment that iterator.

Comment: I just re-read the std::advance, and I thought that it was bounds-safe. But you can advance further than end(), which is UB.