# Can you reverse an vector partly using std::reverse or any other in-built method?

Tags: c++11, vector, reverse

In my practice program there is a vector, which needs to be partly reversed. So for example

```
vector<int> nums;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {nums.push_back(i)}
#than I would want to reverse it somewhat like this
std::reverse(nums.location(3), nums.location(5))
```

This should than make nums look like this: 0 1 **4 3 2** 5 6 7 8 9.
Obviously nums.location() isn't a real method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this through the use of [`iterators`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064983/different-types-of-iterators/1065528#1065528).  An iterator can be imagined as an object specialized to move around the container it came from.

`std::vector::begin` returns an iterator to the first element of a vector, and will thus behave as a *pointer* to the first element of the vector.  To access it, you *dereference the iterator*:

```
auto value_at_first_element = *(v.begin());
```

To move onto the next element, you *increment the iterator*:

```
auto iter_to_second_element = ++(v.begin());
auto value_at_second_element = *iter_to_second_element;
```

It's worth noting that not all iterators behave the same way, and can be split into *categories*.  Most have their own functionality limited by the limitations of their container.  The prime example of this is `std::forward_list`, whose iterator can only move forward through a call to the `++` operator.

---

Study the following solution to your problem, and try to build some intuition on iterators.  Iterators are very powerful and are the cornerstone of algorithms in C++.

```
// If you know the positions already...
std::reverse(nums.begin() + 2, nums.begin() + 5);
// If you need to _find_ the positions...
std::reverse(
    std::find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 2)
  , std::find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 5)
    );
```

[Further reading](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/)

Comment: What does nums.begin() + 2 do exactly? I thought nums.begin() was a reference to the beginning of the vector. Can you just add number to that?

Comment: @Yadeses Yes, you can.  But only because it as an [`iterator`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html), which are _designed_ to support such addition.  Not all iterators support addition, however.  Some only support increments by 1 (the `++` operation).  Give me a few minutes and I'll explain more in the answer.

Comment: You can use `std::next` instead of `operator+()` to work with non-RandomAccessIterator.
std::reverse(std::next(nums.begin(), 2), std::next(nums.begin(), 5));

Comment: I suddenly found something out, maybe it is my mistake, but when I do this the following happens:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Turning the first 5 numbers will result in this:
5 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0

Comment: @Yadeses Upload it on a demoing website like [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com) and recreate the error